# Change font size for categories in a Xceed PropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, propertygrid, xceed

How do I change the font size of a category header in Xceed's PropertyGrid for WPF?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `FontSize` property of the control itself and define an implicit `TrimmedTextBlock` style that sets (preserves) the `FontSize` of the header:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid ... FontSize="20">
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="xctk:TrimmedTextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>
        ...
    </xctk:PropertyGrid.Resources>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

Comment: Changing the TrimmedTextBlock property's size only changes the PropertyGrid's header.  It does not change the size of the Category header ("Action" in the image above)

Comment: No, but `FontSize="20"` does. The TrimmedTextBlock is only needed if you don't want to change the size of both the header and the category headers.

Comment: When I use your XAML, changing FontSize changes the size of the font of the property DisplayName and the property value.  But it does not affect the size of the Category header.

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me so please provide a full repo of your issue if you want any further help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's impossible to guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I think that my problem is related to my use of either MahApps or Caliburn.Micro in my WPF app.  When I create a basic WPF app with the PropertyGrid, your solution works.  I suspect that MahApps is somehow taking control of the PropertyGrid's Category font.

Comment: One of the simplest solutions I found was simply to comment-out the MahApps Fonts.xaml ResourceDictionary line in my App.xaml file

Answer (score 0):

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid>
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.CategoryGroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="20" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </xctk:PropertyGrid.CategoryGroupHeaderTemplate>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

mm8's solution did not work for me, however this did.